# Getting the json array from servlet to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, jstl

I have a java servlet that sends a json object to a jsp page in a javascript variabile with array format.

Here is my servlet ( a part of it):

```
List<HistoryLeavesScalar> returnedPastInfo = SaveDAO.getPastInformation(username);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(returnedPastInfo);
String s = jsonArray.toString();
System.out.println("\n\n"+"JSON ARRAY is :  "+s);

HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("jsonArray",jsonArray); 
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/calendar.jsp")
.forward(request, response);
```

that system.out.print JSON is something like this in my console: 
[{"endDate":"2017-04-22","req":"2017-04-19","nr":2,"type":"CO","startDate":"2017-04-20","Dep":"2017-04-19"},{"endDate":"2017-04-22","req":"2017-04-20","nr":3,"type":"CM","startDate":"2017-04-20","Dep":"2017-04-19"}]

This Json Array I want to be visible in javascript tag like this in that format only: ( this is calendar.jsp - a part of it)

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.*"%>
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.jsp.el.*" %> 
    <%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var USER_DAYS   =   [
                <c:forEach items="${jsonArray}" var="jsonArray">


                        {
                            id: '${jsonArray.nr}',
                            date: '${jsonArray.req}',
                            title: '${jsonArray.type}',
                            startDate: '${jsonArray.startDate',
                            endDate: '${jsonArray.endDate',
                            allDay: true,
                            className: 'done'
                        }
               </c:forEach>
    ];
</script>
```

I don't know how to access the values from that json that comes from the servlet in USER_DAYS variable (javascript). How to put the values from json in id, date, title, startDate, endDate.

I don't know if jstl works in a javascript tag. I don't know how to print that values ( whatever they are - it can contain many information, all in that format).

I want to mention that, if I change the javascript variable into somthing like this: it works just fine. But these are values which I have handwritten, but now I want them dynamically...and this information must come from servlet into calendar.jsp.

```
var USER_DAYS   =   [
      {
          id: 1,
          date: '2017-04-05',
          title: 'CO',
          start: new Date(2017, 3, 5),
          end: new Date(2017, 3, 7),
          allDay: true,
          className: 'done'
      },
```

Can someone help  me?

Comment: Just try this in javascript . No need any JSP tags. Directly we can assign model attribute into our js variables.
var USER_DAYS = '${jsonArray}';

Comment: Why don't you just save `s` in session and print it? It's already a correct string representation of the JSON object, no need to create loops and write broken JSON

Comment: Try using `var USER_DAYS = JSON.parse('${jsonArray}');`

Comment: Hey, see my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have it as string:

```
String s = jsonArray.toString();
```

Store `s` in session instead of `jsonArray`;

```
session.setAttribute("jsonArray", s);
```

And print it in the servlet:

```
var USER_DAYS = ${jsonArray};
```

---

**MY TEST**

Java servlet (with sample data):

[image]

`bingo.jsp`:

[image]

HTML result:

[image]

Rendered result:

[image]

It works.

Comment: I think before you gonna treat `USER_DAYS` as a json object, you should parse it first, isn't it?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna No, because it won't be a string once printed. It will not be printed as string. It will be printed as `var USER_DAYS = {[.....]}`

Comment: can you give me a fiddle?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna No, AFAIK there is no online fiddle tool for Servlets supporting JSTL too. You can try on your own though.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna This doesn't have the java part, which is required to show you that parsing isn't needed.

Comment: `JSTL` render `jsonArray` as a string, not like json object.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna It seems that you are somewhat lazy to try it yourself. See my edit. It works. The next time, please do some test before saying that something doesn't work.

Comment: But the original OP want a json object that has a different key from source as well. `id: '${jsonArray.nr}',date: '${jsonArray.req}',`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Keys can be changed in the servlet itself. Writing a loop that constructs a json array like the OP is trying to do will lead to bugs that in some scenarios will make the JSON invalid (Like unescaped characters). The JSON library already handles all cases, so my approach would still be to change keys in servlet and render the jsonArray as string as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this

```
<script>
    var DAYS = '${jsonArray}';
    if(DAYS.length > 0 ){
    var USER_DAYS = {
            id: DAYS[0].nr,
            date: DAYS[0].req,
            title: DAYS[0].type,
            startDate: new Date(DAYS[0].startDate),
            endDate: new Date(DAYS[0].endDate),
            allDay: true,
            className: 'done'
        };
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your `jsonString` to javascript `JSON` object. Then you want to change some of the object key's of your `json` object, delete one more extra key `[e.g "Dep":"2017-04-19"]` and at last want add two key's with values in your final json object.

```
allDay: true,
className: 'done'
```

Here is the solution.set data as a json string.

```
session.setAttribute("jsonArray",jsonArray.toString());
```

In your jsp

```
var USER_DAYS = JSON.parse('${jsonArray}');
```

This will make a `JSON` object named `USER_DAYS`.
And at last modify your JSON object,

```js
var USER_DAYS = JSON.parse('[{"endDate":"2017-04-22","req":"2017-04-19","nr":2,"type":"CO","startDate":"2017-04-20","Dep":"2017-04-19"},{"endDate":"2017-04-22","req":"2017-04-20","nr":3,"type":"CM","startDate":"2017-04-20","Dep":"2017-04-19"}]');

console.log('Original JSON = ' +JSON.stringify(USER_DAYS));

USER_DAYS.forEach(function(e) {
   e.id = e.nr;
   delete e.nr;
   e.date = e.req;
   delete e.req;
   e.title=e.type;
   delete e.type;
   e.allDay= true;
   e.className='done';
   delete e.Dep;
   
});

console.log('Modified JSON = '+JSON.stringify(USER_DAYS));
```

See the <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ataur63/fw0b0h2s/1/)</kbd>